# transmitting data from one site to another using $_POST

Tags: php

Is there a way to transmit data from one site to another using the $_POST variable, or a similar one? Just to clarify, I am not talking about form data, and the user is not supposed to notice or have to do anything for the data to be transmitted. The $_GET variable is out of question because that can easily be spoofed in a white box attack. Furthermore the $_SESSION variable is out of question, as I am trying to transmit the data to the page, where I Start the session. Would using the $_COOKIE variable be an option that is comparably safe to the $_POST variable? Are there any other variables, that would be applicable to this situation?

Long story short, my question is can I use the $_POST variable without using a form, and if yes, how? AND/OR is there a way to directly transmit data from one page to another, with a level of security similar to the $_POST command?

```php
** secure_log_in **
#confirmed users identity

header("Location: set_session.php?email=$email&setting_session=yes");

** set_session.php **

if (isset($_GET["setting_session"]))
{
start the session
}
```

The problem is, that if an attacker just tries to access the page set_session.php with the link shown above, as long as they know an email used by a user (we will just assume that the attacker knows an email used for the site) they can easily get access to areas they should not have access to. My question is, is there a way to use the $_POST command to send the $email over.

A way around this problem, may be using a cookie. How easy/difficult would it be for the attacker to create a cookie, with the email address required to access the secure section?

Comment: `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SESSION`, and `$_COOKIE` are all global variables, not commands or functions. If you want to post something to another website, look into [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Thx for the calarification, @aynber I come from a background of python coding, so calling the variables just does not sound right in my head.

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do, and it sounds like you may be misunderstanding what these global variables are and how web applications work in general.  You can, in a very general sense, "transfer data" in a variety of ways.  How these two application communicate is really up to the owners of the applications.  If that's you then you have many options available.  They can share a database, share file system access, one can expose an API (such as an HTTP REST API) and the other can integrate to that API, etc.

Comment: @david what I want to do is send the contents of one variable on one page to another page, in a way, that prevents a user/attacker from manipulating that data

Comment: @The_Moth: Are these pages part of the same application?  If so then they would share the same session, so why can't you use `$_SESSION`?  Aside from that, you can store the data in a database or on the file system if you prefer.  An encrypted cookie is possible, but if you don't want the user to ever have any knowledge of the data at all then sending it to the client just to send it back again is an unnecessary step.

Comment: As @aynber said, you need to do a request to the other website using the CURL library. 

Curl library can do a HTTP POST request with all the data you need to the other website in the background.

Similar to how you use `curl` in command line. The other website will received a normal POST request as if someone sent a form. I [wrote an example](https://github.com/Luxian/php-curl-upload-example/blob/master/send-php55.php) some time ago that shows how to upload files (you can ignore the file upload part and only send the text fields).

Comment: @The_Moth: Based on your edit, it looks like you're overcomplicating this login process.  In the login page, start the "session".  It can be as simple as only setting a single session value and then forwarding the user to this `set_session.php` page which presumably does a lot more "session initialization work".  It can just check for that value to ensure it's okay to proceed.  But trying to securely send a value to the client to have it be sent back to the server is entirely unnecessary here, and it's leading to a lot of confused responses in these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying it a lot longer I noticed, that the best way to solve this is to just include the page, and set a variable on one of the pages, to only run the script when you want to. This should be rather safe, and solves all of the problems and is less resource intensive, as well as faster.